# Getting an accurate scale with differencing widths?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scale

I have a scale that spans the container width 100%, but the scale itself only goes from 10-90. How do I accurately account for this difference? IE: when I input a data-value of 20, how do I get it to properly land on the "20" mark, instead of 20% of the overall scale?

example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLPrMP

```
     <div class="score-scale">
        <ul data-animate="colorScale" data-value="20" class="scaleColors">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <div class="scoreTick"></div>
          <div class="scoreArrow"></div>
        </ul>
        <ul class="scaleTicks">
          <li>10</li>
          <li>20</li>
          <li>30</li>
          <li>40</li>
          <li>50</li>
          <li>60</li>
          <li>70</li>
          <li>80</li>
          <li>90</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

These are the percentages to get to specific marks

- 0 = 10
- 12% = 20
- 24.5% = 30
- 37% = 40
- 49.5% = 50
- 61.5% = 60
- 74% = 70
- 86.5% = 80
- 99% = 90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your percentage remapping the number with the different scale

```
function fixPercentage(val){
 var offsetMin = 10;
 var offsetMax = 90;
 val = (val - offsetMin)/(offsetMax - offsetMin) * 100;

return val;
}
```

and after pass your fixed number

check this pen
https://codepen.io/sassoli/pen/NvqdYG

Comment: I am not exactly sure how you got the answer, but I am happy you did. It works perfectly, thank you!